# How to add values to a Wordpress template file programmatically?

Tags: php, templates, wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress & PHP, so kindly excuse the naivety of the question, if any.

I'm building a plugin where I need to select values from the database and create a new HTML page with the values. I'm using a custom template file.

What I've done till now

1. Extracted the values from database
2. Load & display my own template in my plugin file

> ```
> add_action( 'init', 'leb_add_endpoint' );
>
> function leb_add_endpoint()
> {
>     add_rewrite_endpoint( 'result', EP_PERMALINK );
> }
>
> add_action( 'template_include', 'leb_render_template' );
>
> function leb_render_template($default_template) {
>       //some code removed for brevity
>       if ( ! is_singular() || !isset($wp_query->query_vars['result']) )
>       {
>          return $default_template;
>       }
>
>       $sample_result = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql));
>
>       $default_template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/my-custom-template.php';
>
>       return $default_template;
> }
> ```

The content of `my-custom-template.php` is as follows

```
<?php
/* Template Name: My Template*/

echo '<h1>Testing</h1>';

?>
```

The page gets displayed without any problem. All I want is to insert `$sample_result` and other similar results pulled form database into `my-custom-template.php`

I need to generate dynamic pages based on values pulled from DB. So each time, the final page created might be different. E.g. if one hits `www.example.com/sample-post/result`, a page will be shown with values pulled from the DB. If one hits `www.example.com/another-sample-post/result`, a different page will be shown with different values. Both these pages will have the same design, only a few values will be different. This is what I'm trying to achieve.

How can I do that? Please help me. I'm stuck. :(

Comment: template_include is used only to override WordPress's default template. you can pull data directly from the template page if you need it there. I don't really understand what do you need here, but i hope you give more clarification.

Comment: Actually, I've added an endpoint & when the user goes to the endpoint, I need to display a custom page. Let me edit the code for more clarity.

Comment: Hi @hutchbat, Edited for more clarity. Kindly check.

Comment: "result" is a custom query var that is already define, right ?

Comment: Yes, it's just a variable that stores values retrieved from the db. I've 5-6 values e.g. $sample_result1, $sample_result2 etc. They hold numeric and text values. I need to get these values printed on the final page. These values will vary depending on which url the user is hitting. I have that logic figured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to define "result" in query vars.
2. Use EP_ROOT Endpoint Mask ( result/{var} is located in the root )
3. Inside template_include hook, you can find result value inside $wp_query object.

I've already tested the code

```
// Add a new var to query vars
function result_add_query_vars( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'result';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'result_add_query_vars' );

// Add endpoint
function result_add_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'result', EP_ROOT );
}
add_action( 'init', 'result_add_endpoint');

// change the template
function result_render_template($template)
{
    global $wp_query;

     if ( array_key_exists( 'result', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {

        $result = get_query_var('result');

        $new_template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/my-custom-template.php';
        return $new_template;

    } else {

        return $template;

    }
}
add_action( 'template_include', 'result_render_template' );
```

Now you can retrieve the query var in your custom template

```
/*
 *  Template Name: My Custom Template
 */

$result = get_query_var('result');

echo $result;
```

Comment: I've already completed this step. The page is up, it's just that I can only show static content in it. In your example, inside `result_render_template`, I've some DB queries that pull values form db. (already done too). Now I've those values in $var1, $var2 etc. (already done too). Now I want to insert those values in `my-custom-template.php`. How can I do that? The process you've mentioned is already done & working.

Comment: result_render_template won't return any data. Your DB queries should be called from my-custom-template.php !! is it important to make those DB queries before you include the template ?

Comment: I've already made those DB queries before calling `my-custom-template.php` , it's just that I've not shown them in the example for brevity.

Comment: Move the DB Queries to my-custom-template.php then let's see what happens

Comment: I can move the db queries to `my-custom-template.php` but then how would I be able to pass the `$result` value to the `my-custom-template.php`, I need that to run the query

Comment: $result = (get_query_var('result')) ? get_query_var('result') : '';

Comment: Ok, I get it. My bad. I can use `get_query_var` in the `my-custom-template.php` too. Let me try & get back. Man, I'm stupid. :S

Comment: hutchbat, I think the answer should include an example of `my-custom-template.php` pulling the query_var, that's where @LittleLebowski is missing the code ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well why don't you use ***$wp_query*** Inside your ***my-custom-template.php***

```
<?php
    /* Template Name: My Template*/

    global $wp_query;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($wp_query); // Use this in case you want to see what else do you have with you.
    echo '<pre/>';
    // Now you can use $wp_query to build your dynamic query at run time.
    // This will allow you to perform task at run time

?>
```

### To Retrieve Meta

If you have saved something as a meta then

```
<?php
     $meta_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single );
?>
```

### To Retrieve Child Post

If you want to retrieve child posts then

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) :

        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            // Do your stuff here such as below
            the_title();
            the_content();

        endwhile;
    else:
        echo 'No Post Found';
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: I can use `$wp_query` inside my template, but how can I pass the values I've retrieved to the template file then? Sorry, I'm new to php, this sounds like a stupid question, but that's the stage I'm in now. :(

Comment: That's fine. See print_r $wp_query. You'll find loads of stuff in it. Such as page name is located at $wp_query->query['name'] & query_vars are located at $wp_query->query_vars & page is is located at $wp_query->queried_object_id. Once you have page id then you can also retrieve other information associated with it as also described in answer. Can you tell me, what sort of information you trying to retrieve from DB. I might be able to help better in that regard. @LittleLebowski

Answer (score 0):

1) Write this function in function.php in your active template.

```
 function leb_render_template() {
  //some code removed for brevity
   //$sql = 'YOUR_QUERY_CODE'
   $sample_result = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql));
   return $my_template;   
  }      

 add_action('wp_ajax_leb_render_template', 'leb_render_template');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_leb_render_template', 'leb_render_template');
```

2) Call function in your custom template.

```
    <?php
      /* Template Name: My Template*/
       echo '<h1>Testing</h1>';
      $result = leb_render_template();
      print_r($result); // Print Your function output. 
      ?>
```

Comment: Hi @er_Rajendraa, I've edited the question for more clarity. The page is getting displayed, not a problem. I want to include values like `$sample_result` in the template from the function `leb_render_template()`

Comment: Hi @LittleLebowski just call your function in your custom page like $result = leb_render_template();  print_r($result). I think it should work.

Comment: I've edited the question. Can you kindly check. The page needs to render on endpoint. Hence the code.